# Branding for multiple organizations in a single tenant - Azure AD / Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Azure AD B2C sits on top of Azure AD. Azure AD / Azure AD B2C allows for company branding. This affects emails, the sign in page, etc.

We have a need to present a different branded experienced for two organizations within a single Azure AD B2C tenant. I know I can change the user flow branding with custom HTML in a custom policy. But, this doesn't affect emails (such as password reset) and the sign-in page to the admin panel.

Is anyone aware of a way to have branding for two different organizations handled in a single Azure AD / Azure AD B2C tenant?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is an option with user flow, but with custom policies, you can make use of claim resolvers to get information about the authorization request that can then be used to control things like which API to call to send emails. Information on claim resolvers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview)

Depending on the setup, you can also make use of policy inheritance to just have two different policies that make small changes to a parent policy that handles most of the work

Comment: Interesting. Lets take forgot password link for example. It uses Microsoft functionality (in the custom policy) to send a code via email, and that email has the company logo on it as configured in company branding. Are you saying I can call the microsoft API that does this in a different way to change branding? Or, are you referring only to custom/external APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you and clarify few things.

With Azure AD B2C you have two options for branding customization:

1. Company branding - this is what you configure directly in the tenant settings. It is limited and you can read more about these limitations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#how-do-i-customize-verification-emails--the-content-and-the--from---field--sent-by-azure-ad-b2c-). When you enable company branding you can display your company logo and custom background in the login/registration/password reset pages of the Azure AD B2C. This branding will be also used when signing into tenant.
   2.Custom branding per custom policy/application. With such approach you can customize the look and feel of each custom policy which represents you login/registration/password reset page.

Noe going further. For the email customization you will have to utilize external mail delivery service like [SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). With such approach you can use email template ID and decide basing on the brand, which email template use to send verification email with code for instance.
Such approach can be only handled in the custom policies.

Having said that, you have one Azure AD B2C tenant which can provide multiple branding experience (including emails). Please remember that in the Azure AD B2C architecture, Azure AD B2C tenant = one organization which can manage different brands. In your scenario (if I hopefully understood correctly) you would like to have multiple brands in one Azure AD B2C tenants which results in:

1. Separate custom policies for (login/registration/password reset) for each brand and application set, where specific branding is applied using HTML/CSS files.
2. Separate email templates which will be applied basing on the "brand ID" so verification emails will be branded too and aligned with the brand that was used.

Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: Is there any mechanism through which the logon page to the admin console itself can have two brands? I know it's nitpicky, but I'm curious.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option.